# zip command options on mac/linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zip, compression

**Folder to zip**

I've a folder `/resources/html/article` (with css/js files)

**Terminal Command**

I'm executing following command to generate a zip file in node.js in order to closely mimic what a software utility does.

```
cd /resources/html/ 
&& $(which zip) -r article.zip article
```

**A. My version**

When I change the filename manually, let's say `article.zip` to `store.zip`, it extracts into folder called **article**

*My version is still getting extracted to the original folder name.*

**B. Software Utility Version**

When I change the filename manually, let's say `article.zip` to `utility.zip`, it extracts into folder called **utility**

*Utility's version is using the current filename of the archive.*

**Hypothesis**

I think because of the difference in extraction paths, server is not accepting my version when I upload, and I know file names do get change to temp names on the server when they are uploaded, that's why the server is unable to find the extracted folder.

**Question:**

In what way should I create the zip, any options should I specify that it closely mimic's the utility version.

Comment: Is it possible that the zip file contains folder `article`? so, it would be something like `store.zip/article/files-inside-folder`

Comment: not sure about your question, the article folder only has css and js folder

Comment: So you want to zip whatever is in the /resources/html/ directory with the same name as the directory or file? Say, you have article directory then you want article.zip and in case you have utility directory then you want utility.zip, right?

Comment: @GouravChawla I'm achieving to get the right zip name, it's the default extraction path that's not correct, my version extracts to original folder name and utility's version extracts to archive's current name.

Comment: Try this: `cd /resources/html/ && zip -r article.zip article/*`

Comment: It still retaining the original folder name, I'm trying something different, going inside the article folder, creating a zip and then moving the zip one level up, any shortcuts for that?

Comment: it works, I zipped the contents of the folder and that's what changes the default path and server accepts my file. I'm editing with my question with an answer, can you make this command efficient?

Comment: There is also this: `unzip article.zip -d /any/directory/path` . This will unzip the article.zip in that  path.

Comment: thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip -r article.zip article` will include `article/` in every path name in the zip archive. So when you unzip, you unzip to the `article/` directory, no matter what you name the .zip file. The name of the .zip file has no bearing whatsoever on what the result of the unzipping is named.

To get rid of the directory name, you would need to do the zip operation from inside the directory, so that the names passed to zip on the command line do not contain that directory name.

Comment: is there a way to issue the zip command for the "contents" of the folder instead of having to do `cd /path/to/folder`? my command is below, notice the dot at the end, I want to get rid of this `cd` command

Comment: `cd /resources/html/article && $(which zip) -r ../article.zip .`

Comment: No, the zip command does not have an option to operate from a different location.

Answer (score 0):

I went inside the folder and zipped *.* and this is what changed the default extraction path to the filename, and moved the zip file one level above.

```
cd /resources/html/article 
&& $(which zip) -rp article . 
&& mv article.zip ../article.zip
```

Shortened my command (got rid of mv)

```
cd /resources/html/article 
&& $(which zip) -rp ../article.zip .
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the folder that you would like to zip you can use

```
zip -r FileName.zip .
```